# Handle selected event with bootstrap Typeahead

Tags: javascript, typeahead, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to use bootstrap typeahead. 
I am having trouble handling which item has been selected.

Below is the code I have so for

```
  var bindto = $(".search.typeahead");
        bindto.typeahead({
            source: function (query, response) {
                var map = {};
                var advicesearchList = [];
                return $.ajax({
                    url: "/Advice/AutoComplete",
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    data: { querystring: query },
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function (i, result) {
                            map[result.Title] = result;
                            advicesearchList.push(result.Title);
                        });
                        response(advicesearchList);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).on("typeahead:selected", function (e, o) {
            console.log("item selected");

        });
```

What would be the correct way to detect what the user has selected from one of the items in the list

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try using the afterSelected option:

```
    var bindto = $(".search.typeahead");
    bindto.typeahead({
    source: function (query, response) {
        //your code...
    }, afterSelect: function (data) {
        //print the data to developer tool's console
        console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

[Docs](https://github.com/bassjobsen/Bootstrap-3-Typeahead)